# Where to see font files loaded by chrome in the inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, font-face, web-inspector

What tab in chrome inspector shows the font files you're loading via font-face? I can't find it under resources. I'm having an issue where one group of font-family files are loading, but another font-family is not. I have checked everything from going directly to the URL and seeing they are indeed present, but I would like to look in the inspector and see it loading the one font-family but not the other. Is this possible with chrome?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can view the downloaded web fonts using the Network tab:

[image: Google Chrome Network tab showing downloaded web fonts]

Comment: I see what you mean. It does appear they are there in your screenshot. I fixed my issue and they still don't appear there, although I know for a fact they are being loaded now and used. I'll have to continue searching. The googlefonts are showing there, but fonts located on our own servers are not...

Comment: The screenshot shows the loading of the CSS file which points to the fonts, but it doesn't actually show the loaded fonts; just the file that points to them/where to load them from.

Comment: If a font is not appearing in the network tab when it should be, make sure the font isn't installed on your computer

Comment: I discovered that in Chrome 63, the fonts are only actually downloaded if they are used for styling.

Comment: This does not always reflect that the font is being used where you expect it. to know for sure, you need to check for rendered fonts at the bottom of the computed styles tab to ensure the font-family that is being used, and weather or not it is a resource local to your device, or loaded over network through cdn

Answer (score 83):

You can also select any text node in the elements panel, then look at the bottom of the [computed styles](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that) tab to see what fonts are rendered for that element

[image: Google Chrome styles tab showing computed rendered fonts]

Comment: This should be the (new) accepted answer! :) I would've never thought to scroll all the way to the very bottom beneath all of those computed properties! I've been looking for this for hours. Thanks @cfg!

Comment: Anytime @jdunk, Glad to help.

Comment: In the section "Rendered fonts", all I see is "- Network resource (310 glyphs)".
What does it mean?

Comment: @greg that means you're at least calling a font from a cdn somewhere, as it's being resources over network and not locally hosted on your machine. It looks like it perhaps doesn't have a name??

Comment: Note that this section will not appear for all elements, only elements containing text as a direct child. So, for example, you will not see "Rendered Fonts" for the `<body>` tag but will see it for paragraph tags, table cells, etc.

Comment: Would be nice if it indicated the actual file.

Comment: If someone could use firefox, there is tab in the firefox where we can see all the loaded fonts, if you click on the inspector tab, there is fonts tab. Wonder why chrome does not have such a feature

Answer (score 26):

## The best way so far

You can actaully do `rightclick: inspect > Application (on the top tabs) > Frames (scroll on the left tabs)` Then you can find a `Font` section where all loaded fonts are listed. It also has a preview for the fonts. It lists all fonts that are loaded in any possible way.

**The best part is that, It also previews them on the right, to make it even easier to find the one**

[image: Application tab]

Then you can right-click on the one you chose and click open in a new tab, and it downloads it. Then you can add a .woff at the end of the filename and use it anywhere you like. (you can get its extension on the bottom of the preview too)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this doesn't answer the question directly, one thing that helped, in my case, was to:

1. open the Sources tab;
2. Find the stylesheet that has the relevant font face declarations;
3. search for `@font-face` to find the font name.

You can also jump to the stylesheet directly from the Network tab by clicking on the stylesheet name.

The presence of a font face declaration doesn't necessarily mean that the font is being downloaded successfully by the browser, but it's helpful to see the actual *name* of the font.

In my case, it turned out that the font name wasn't declared as `DM Sans`, but `Dmsans`.

Changing to `font-family: Dmsans, sans-serif;` fixed the issue for me.

[image: screenshot of a @font-face declaration]