# Rails custom fonts not loading. Do I need to precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this font:

```
app/assets
├── fonts
│   └── Reckless-Medium.otf
```

and I have this `css.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Reckless-Medium';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/Reckless-Medium.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-color: orange;
}

$reckless-medium: 'Reckless-Medium';

.results-list {
    display: block;
    font-family: $reckless-medium;
    max-width: 400px;
```

but the font is not working. A few questions:

1. What am I missing?
2. I don't have a good eye for font... what's a good way to tell if this is working or not? Do I have a problem with my css? I guess I can just stick in like font-color:  to see if the css is working? Is there a better way?

If this is on production server on Digital Ocean, what do I need to do to make these fonts work?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450218

Comment: regarding the compiling, I have answered somethign here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421137/rails-5-heroku-assets-are-not-loaded-in-production-but-works-in-localhost/52423496#52423496 Though your font should be working in development.. is it the case ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409600/rails-4-why-are-fonts-not-loading-in-production